# Hopper remote debugging

Tags: ida, debugging, hopper, remote

I  have hopper on my Mac and work fine for disassemble, now I want to debug an exe file, but I have a problem...
with ida you can remote debugging, is there any method where I have hopper on my Mac (client) and start a remote debugger on windows/linux so I can also dynamically debug elf and exe?
Thank you.

Comment: RTFM. If this is not in the manual, this feature is not available.